# How to group array elements which has same index in php

Tags: php, arrays

I Have following array and

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [70] => Array ( [0] => d ) ) 
    [1] => Array ( [71] => Array ( [0] => a ) ) 
    [2] => Array ( [71] => Array ( [0] => c ) ) 
    [3] => Array ( [71] => Array ( [0] => d ) ) 
    [4] => Array ( [72] => Array ( [0] => b ) ) 
    [5] => Array ( [73] => Array ( [0] => a ) ) 
    [6] => Array ( [73] => Array ( [0] => c ) ) 
    [7] => Array ( [74] => Array ( [0] => a ) ) 
    [8] => Array ( [75] => Array ( [0] => a ) ) 
)
```

I want to make the above array like as following one

```
Array (
    [70] => Array ( [0] => c ) 
    [71] => Array ( [1] => b [2] => c ) 
    [72] => Array ( [2] => c ) 
    [73] => Array ( [0] => a [2] => c ) 
    [74] => Array ( [4] => c ) 
    [75] => Array ( [5] => c ) 
    )
```

Please help me how to make this in php?

Comment: It's unclear what relationship the two arrays have. Can you elaborate and/or verify that the arrays are actually what you intend them to be?

Comment: Hi,I am building a online quiz application, The first array which represents question id that is 71,72.. and correct answers 70=>d (only one answer),71=>a,c,d,(71 has 3 correct answers which is multiple answers) which is retrieved from database,and the second array which is candidate answers it also having question id 71,72,.. and relative answers ,I want to compare both array and want to display the user what is correct answer if he selected wrong option,or please tell me good way to show when quiz completes candidate has to know their result and correct answer for his option,

Comment: how did you came up with `[70] => Array ( [0] => c` as an answer? your example has `[70] => Array ( [0] => d`

Comment: I have retrieved from my database table,and store it an array.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys!